# Between com campo tipo varchar

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho dois campos onde é colocado uma data inicial e final:

```
<form name="filtroClientes" action="consulta_contas.php" method="POST">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nomefiltrar" style="color:#E4CDAC; font-size: 17px; font-family:Arial">Observação</label>
                <input type="text" class="teste" id="nomefiltrar" name="nomefiltrar" />
                <p>
                <label for="dataemissaoinicialfiltrar" style="color:#E4CDAC; font-size: 17px; font-family:Arial">Data Emissao Inicial</label>
                <input type="date" id="dataemissaoiniciofiltrar" class="teste" name="dataemissaoiniciofiltrar" />
                <p>
                <label for="dataemissaofiltrar" style="color:#E4CDAC; font-size: 17px; font-family:Arial">Data Emissao Final</label>
                <input type="date" class="teste" id="dataemissaofinalfiltrar" name="dataemissaofinalfiltrar" />             



                <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="filtrar"/>

            </div>


            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-roxo">Filtrar</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Através de uma função eu recupero o valor destes campos e realizo uma query para filtrar conforme os valores colocados nesse campo:
registra_contas.php:

```
function filtraContas(){
    $contas = '';
    $banco = abrirBanco();
    if(isset($_POST['nomefiltrar'])){
        $nomefiltrar = $_POST['nomefiltrar'];
    }else{
        $nomefiltrar = '';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['dataemissaoiniciofiltrar'])){
        $dataemissaoinicio = $_POST['dataemissaoiniciofiltrar'];

    }else{
        $dataemissaoinicio = '';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['dataemissaofinalfiltrar'])){
        $dataemissaofinal = $_POST['dataemissaofinalfiltrar'];
    }else{
        $dataemissaofinal = '';
    }

    $sql = " SELECT c.*, c.dataemissao as dataemissaoformatada, c.datavencimento as datavencimentoformatada, p.nome, e.nome_especie FROM contas c INNER JOIN pessoa p ON (c.id_fornecedor = p.id) INNER JOIN especies e ON (c.id_especie = e.id) WHERE observacao LIKE '%$nomefiltrar%' OR c.dataemissao BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$dataemissaoinicio', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('$dataemissaofinal ', '%d/%m/%Y') ";
    $resultado = $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $contas[] = $row;
    }
    return $contas;
}
```

Porém, o between não está sendo aplicado. Porque isso ocorre?
O campo de dataemissao é um campo do tipo varchar no banco.
Percebi que mesmo se eu alterar o campo de "date" para "text" e retirar o STR_TO_DATE, o between ainda não é realizado, acredito que deveria funcionar já que no banco é tipo varchar e nesse campo estaria pegando no formato text??

Comment: Seu código está conceitualmente errado, não é possível filtrar uma data em um campo VARCHAR. Caso seja realmente necessário, você deve converter o campo do banco de dados para Date e não apenas o parâmetro que está sendo requisitado.

Comment: Verdade. Estou convertendo todos agora, mas continuo não conseguindo filtrar:  $sql = " SELECT c.*, p.nome, e.nome_especie FROM contas c INNER JOIN pessoa p ON (c.id_fornecedor = p.id) INNER JOIN especies e ON (c.id_especie = e.id) WHERE observacao LIKE '%$nomefiltrar%' OR STR_TO_DATE(c.dataemissao, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('$dataemissaoinicio', '%d/%m/%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('$dataemissaofinal', '%d/%m/%Y') ";

Comment: Execute o seguinte SELECT no seu banco e veja se os dois campos retornam os dados na mesma estrutura (tipagem):  
`SELCT STR_TO_DATE(c.dataemissao, '%d/%m/%Y') as DatadoBanco, STR_TO_DATE('06/02/2018', '%d/%m/%Y') from contas c`.  

Mais uma coisa, você não pode alterar o tipo do campo no banco? Quero dizer apagar o campo existente e recria-lo como Date?

Comment: O banco retorna corretamente, acredito que o problema seja o c.observacao LIKE '%nomefiltrar%', se não tiver nada preenchido ele vai retornar todos os registros, certo?

tentei fazer um if:

 if(isset($_POST['nomefiltrar'])){
  $nomefiltrar = $_POST['nomefiltrar'];
 }else{
  $nomefiltrar = '9';
 }

mas ainda retorna todos os resultados.

Comment: Tente capturar o SQL exato que seu código está gerando. E como dica, teste seu SQL por partes... adicionando os filtros um por um...